# Is there a way to obtain the request information from javax.ws.rs.Client in Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am trying to make a standard in logging for the projects that are build on top of jersey, and I want to provide a simple way to log the request information and response in case an exception occurs. The following code illustrates my idea :

```
    Client client = null;
    Response response = null;
    try {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        response = client.target("<URL>")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(entity);
    } catch( Exception ex) {
        //Send information for exception mapping to a JSON log
        throw new ServiceException( client,response );
    }
```

The problem is how can I obtain the following in my `ServiceException` class:

```
    String url = client.getUri().toString(); //only one I could get using WebTarget
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = client.getHeaders();
    String body = client.getEntity();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = client.getQueryParams();    
    String method = client.getMethod();
```

I tried accessing the `WebTarget` but without luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey has [logging support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html) for both the client side and the server side. The documentation shows how to register it with the `Client`. It can also be registered with the `WebtTarget`.

If you are not satisfied with the results, and you want to implement your own, I would just implement it the same way that Jersey does: with a combination of a `WriterInterceptor` to log the request entity stream<sup>**1**</sup> and a `Client(Request|Response)Filter`<sup>**2**</sup> to get the other parts of the  request and response (like headers and request line).

You can look at the source for the [`ClientLoggingFilter`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b08/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/ClientLoggingFilter.java) and the [`LoggingInterceptor`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b08/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingInterceptor.java) to get some ideas for your implementation.

---

<sup>**1** - It needs to use the interceptor, instead of just using the filter for everything, because the filter will only give you the pre-seriazlied object, which can be anything, which is difficult to log. It's easier to do generic logging with the input stream</sup>.

<sup>**2** - See [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)</sup>

Comment: Yeah after days of looking it seems I can't avoid the filter registration on each call or making a wrapper that would do the same, thank you for pointing to the source of jersey I will have a look!